# Sorting in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file that has to be sorted by 'Priority Score' and 'Tested',

Priority is already sorted but cant seem to figure out how to sort 'Tested' by a certain string.. ie "Pending"

Heres what I got so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('TestsPopulation_04-12-2022-09-03-39.xlsx')

df.sort_values(['Priority Score', 'Tested'], ascending=False)

new_df = df.drop(columns=['Filtering list here'])

print(new_df.head(60))
```

It prints as the following :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SZh4.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkoaL.png

Goal is to first sort out by 'Priority Score' which holds an integer as a value
then go over 'Tested' and if something comes up as 'Pending' print the whole column.

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you need to make a filter and index the dataframe on it. 

Your description isn't clear because NONE of those columns have "pending" in them. If you could updating your question to be more specific that would be helpful. It's not clear to me if you want to filter based on columns or rows. 

Try https://datatofish.com/filter-pandas-dataframe/ and https://towardsdatascience.com/filtering-data-frames-in-pandas-b570b1f834b9

Comment: Apologies, Pending is way lower down the list hence the need to sort it this way

https://i.imgur.com/B1FGLHR.png


First Column holds the value "Tested"
everything below it is either Passed, Fail or Pending

Another value we have in the same column is Priority Score which holds integers

It should first be sorted by Priority Score
and from highest Priority Score go over the 'Tested' tab and find values which hold 'Pending'

Once found print the whole column

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to print only rows with Tested == Pending? Should any rows with Tested equal to Pass or Fail be printed? If only Pending, then we would first filter based on Pending (discarding any rows with values other than Pending) and then there would be no need to include Tested in the sort column, just Priority. Please confirm.

Comment: @constantstranger
exactly, only pending should be printed sorted by Priority Score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can do. It will first filter for Tested == PENDING, then sort in descending order by Priority and secondarily by Tested. However, if we have already ruled out all rows that do not have Tested == PENDING, then the secondary sort on Tested shouldn't be necessary.

Note also that your code was not capturing the result of `sort_values()`.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('TestsPopulation_04-12-2022-09-03-39.xlsx')
print(f"\nINPUT from .xlsx\n{df}")
new_df = df[df['Tested'] == 'PENDING'].sort_values(['Priority Score', 'Tested'], ascending=False).drop(columns=['Column to drop', 'Another to drop'])
print(f"\nOUTPUT after filtering for PENDING and sorting\n{new_df.head(60)}")
```

Test case contents of .xlsx:

```
Priority Score  Tested  Column to drop  Another to drop
5   Fail    x   a
5   PENDING x   a
4   Pass    y   b
3   Pass    x   a
3   Fail    x   a
3   PENDING x   a
2   PENDING y   b
1   Fail    x   a
```

Output:

```
INPUT from .xlsx
   Priority Score   Tested Column to drop Another to drop
0               5     Fail              x               a
1               5  PENDING              x               a
2               4     Pass              y               b
3               3     Pass              x               a
4               3     Fail              x               a
5               3  PENDING              x               a
6               2  PENDING              y               b
7               1     Fail              x               a

OUTPUT after filtering for PENDING and sorting
   Priority Score   Tested
1               5  PENDING
5               3  PENDING
6               2  PENDING
```

**UPDATE**: Here's how to specify columns to keep, rather than dropping ones we don't want to keep.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('TestsPopulation_04-12-2022-09-03-39.xlsx')
print(f"\nINPUT from .xlsx\n{df}")
columnsToKeep = ['Priority Score', 'Tested', 'Column to keep', 'Another column to keep']
new_df = df[df['Tested'] == 'PENDING'].sort_values(['Priority Score', 'Tested'], ascending=False)[columnsToKeep]
print(f"\nOUTPUT after filtering for PENDING and sorting\n{new_df.head(60)}")
```

Output:

```
INPUT from .xlsx
   Priority Score   Tested Column to drop Another to drop  Column to keep          Another column to keep
0               5     Fail              x               a               0  this row will get filtered out
1               5  PENDING              x               a               1            this row will remain
2               4     Pass              y               b               2          another row to exclude
3               3     Pass              x               a               3                     and another
4               3     Fail              x               a               2                     and another
5               3  PENDING              x               a               1                  another keeper
6               2  PENDING              y               b               0              yet another keeper
7               1     Fail              x               a               1  this row will get filtered out

OUTPUT after filtering for PENDING and sorting
   Priority Score   Tested  Column to keep Another column to keep
1               5  PENDING               1   this row will remain
5               3  PENDING               1         another keeper
6               2  PENDING               0     yet another keeper
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out, Tested is still not sorted
anything else I can add?

Comment: I have updated my answer to label the output: The first part is just echoing my sample input, and the second part is the result, with only PENDING rows sorted in descending order of Priority Score. Note that the index (the leftmost "column" of numbers, though not technically a Pandas column) I have left unchanged (hence it contains the indexes of original rows: 1, 5, 6). Because Tested in the result is always PENDING, it is "sorted". If I am not understanding your goal, please clarify (for example, do you NOT want to eliminate rows where Tested is Pass or Fail?).

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: Excellent! Do you need any additional help? If you're satisfied with the answer, please feel free to mark it as "accepted".

Comment: Would like to ask if there's a method to replace drop? 
there's a long list to filter, is there a way to print only specific columns and ignore the rest?

Comment: Yes, please see my updated answer for an example of how to do this.